# Как получить QAuth PIN код от Twitter

Tags: twitter, аутентификация, token, twitter-api

Нужен PIN код твиттера для аутентификации одного скрипта на python. Не могу понять как его получить из браузера. В документации приведена такая ссылка:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=Z6eEdO8MOmk394WozF5oKyuAv855l4Mlqo7hhlSLik
```

При попытке выполнить такой запрос со своим `acess_token` (взял в настройках приложения), получаю ошибку неверный маркер запроса. Что я делаю не так?